# How to query Google Cloud logs by scope/storage via api or java libs

Tags: api, logging, google-cloud-platform, querying

I have defined log sinks to various storage buckets.
In GCP Logs explorer (https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query) I can specify query scope by project or by specified bucket storages.

How to achieve the same feature (scope by specified storages) using GCP logs api and/or google java libraries ?

Aby links to docs ?

Comment: It seems possible only with GRPC call.

Comment: Using logs API, you can use resourceNames[] parameter. Here BUCKET_ID refers to Log bucket ID not storage bucket ID. Refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/logs/list?apix_params=%7B%22parent%22%3A%22projects%2Fproject-327504%22%7D#query-parameters) and let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same feature using GCP logs api, by using resourceNames[] Query parameter. Here BUCKET_ID refers to Log bucket ID not storage bucket ID. Refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/logs/list?apix_params=%7B%22parent%22%3A%22projects%2Fproject-327504%22%7D#query-parameters) for information.

In resource-oriented APIs, resources are named entities, and resource names are their identifiers. Each resource must have its own unique [resource name](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/resource_names). The resource name is made up of the ID of the resource itself, the IDs of any parent resources, and its API service name.

gRPC APIs should use scheme-less [URIs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986) for resource names. They generally follow the REST URL conventions and behave much like network file paths. They can be easily mapped to REST URLs: see the [Standard Methods](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/standard_methods) section for details.